# In Memory SQLite Nhibernate Keyword not supported: 'fulluri' error

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to create an "in memory" SQLite db in my Nhibernate base class for testing purposes. When I run Unit Tests on my test factory, I get:

`Unable to create instance of class NhibernateTests.Tests. Error: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'fulluri'..`

I am using SQLite version 1.0.82.0 so I know I am using a version that supports FullUri ([see here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki))

Here is my connection string:

`ConnectionString = "FullUri=file:memorydb.db?mode=memory&cache=shared";`

I also tried:

`ConnectionString = "FullUri=file::memory:?cache=shared";`

with the same result. Any clue as to what would be causing this?

Comment: How did you solve the issue of NHibernate using the wrong dialect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Data Source=:memory:;` is all you need for the connection string

Comment: I get: `Unable to create instance of class NhibernateTests.Tests. Error: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'version'..`

Comment: Apparently I had a bug where the db dialect that was being used was SQL Server instead of SQLite... the proper connection string is, in fact: `"FullUri=file:memorydb.db?mode=memory&cache=shared"` Your comment led me to the next error which led to figure out the real issue, so I'm marking your answer as correct